# C# Regex - Add character once before consecutive occurrences of another character

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to **prepend `\r`** **once** before consecutive occurrence(s) of `\n` (if it is not there already).

```
string myString = "This\nis a\n\nstring that\r\n\n has many\r\nlines"
```

The result of the regex expression should return this result,

```
string myString = "This\r\nis a\r\n\nstring that\r\n\n has many\r\nlines"
```

Any ideas on how to get this done.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to keep \r\n\n intead of transforming to \r\n\r\n ?

Comment: Yes. I just want \r before all consecutive \n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a sequence of `\n` that doesn't begin with an `\r`.

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"([^\r\n]|^)(\n)+", "$1\r$2");
```

Since the first group (any character other than \r or \n, or a beginning of the string) will be a part of the match, we need to rewrite it (`$1`) and then prepend the `\r` to the second group (the sequence of `\n`-s).

Please verify my answer, especially a case when `\n` is a first character in the string, as I'm unsure about the behaviour of `$1` then.

An example, replace on:

```
\n \r\n\n abc\n\r\n \nx\ny\r\n
```

should result in:

```
\r\n \r\n\n abc\r\n\r\n \r\nx\r\ny\r\n
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error on running this,
 "{"parsing \"(([^\\r\\n]|^)(\\n)+\" - Not enough )'s."}"

Comment: Ye, there's a typo, that first opening parentheses is not needed. I edited the answer.